# What is the resulting format of signing a file with openssl?

Tags: openssl

I'm using this command to sign a file:

```
openssl dgst -binary -sha1 -out signedFile.bin -sign file.pem plainText
```

I want to know what format is is the output of this command. My purpose is to parse the result and extract the hash array.

What is the format? Are there any tools to parse the result?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand. In that command you specify that it should be output as a .pem file. Which format are you referring to?

Comment: You are asking for a binary format signature file.  Consider using -hex instead of -binary in the command and see if the result is more like what you expect.

Comment: @ilikebeets the (only) output specified is signedFile.bin which is not supposed to be and is not PEM. Many openssl data files are PEM by default but not this one.

Answer (score 2):

*IF* file.pem contains an RSA privatekey (in which case that name is misleading) the output is a "bare" RSA [PKCS#1(v1.5)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3447.txt) signature -- an N-bit number where N is the modulus size, rounded up if necessary which it rarely is because people generally use key sizes like 1024 and 2048, without any of the metadata normally used with a signature. `dgst -sign` defaults to `-binary` so that is redundant (the *hash-only* form of `dgst` does not) but as @zedman9991 says you can ask for `-hex`.

But it makes no sense to parse this. It's a number. If you want to "recover" the signed hash value, which PKCS#1 supports but other RSA formats may not and other algorithms like DSA and ECDSA definitely do not, you need to (1) do a modexp-e computation (often inaccurately called "decrypting with the public key"), then (2) unpad, then (3) ASN.1 decode. "parse" might reasonably be used to mean (2) or (3) or both. You can write a C program to do these in maybe 20 lines. Given the binary file, `rsautl -verify` does (1) and (2) (given v1.5 padding which is the `dgst -sign` default) and you can do (3) manually or with `asn1parse`:

```
c:\work>echo test >in & od -tx1 in
0000000 74 65 73 74 20 20 0d 0a
0000010

c:\work>openssl dgst -sha1 -hex in
SHA1(in)= a02bfe060e0d7857137b7082124541237ed740c7

c:\work>openssl dgst -sha1 -sign rsakey.pem in >sig & od -tx1 sig
0000000 53 e3 68 70 69 d9 fd 1f b1 83 6e eb 1c 6f 58 ab
0000020 b5 44 88 3f d2 67 19 21 9b 95 39 bb ce 2d 7c ac
0000040 51 03 c3 a5 61 7e 47 f6 4b e1 c0 4a 74 ee 7f 29
0000060 b2 cc ff 91 20 97 c4 f9 2e 3e 9f 61 06 62 e3 fe
0000100 ea 4c 3f a6 3b da b4 03 62 81 a7 8c 91 b7 d5 49
0000120 8c d1 e9 92 ff 4b 97 c0 b5 74 59 4d 19 e1 57 c9
0000140 a8 98 f4 c8 df 70 b4 89 57 b0 24 f5 b0 a9 69 b4
0000160 dd ed a0 26 73 bd ca ad a0 f9 e2 0e ea fe 39 8d

c:\work>openssl rsautl -verify -inkey rsakey.pem <sig >rec & od -tx1 rec
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
0000000 30 21 30 09 06 05 2b 0e 03 02 1a 05 00 04 14 a0
0000020 2b fe 06 0e 0d 78 57 13 7b 70 82 12 45 41 23 7e
0000040 d7 40 c7
0000043

c:\work>openssl asn1parse -inform der <rec
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=  33 cons: SEQUENCE
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=   9 cons: SEQUENCE
    4:d=2  hl=2 l=   5 prim: OBJECT            :sha1
   11:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL
   13:d=1  hl=2 l=  20 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:A02BFE060E0D7857137B7082124541237ED740C7
```

The value of the last field (OCTET STRING) of the "recovered" signature DER, which is also its last 20 octets in this case, is the hash value.

(For a simple example I used a 1024-bit RSA key and thus a 128-byte signature. RSA-1024 is now considered at some risk of being broken in the foreseeable future, so at least 1536 and usually 2048 or more is generally required for secure applications.)